# Terraform: YAML file rendering issue in storage section of container linux config of flatcar OS

Tags: terraform, coreos-ignition

I am trying to generate a file by template rendering to pass to the user data of the ec2 instance. I am using the third party terraform provider to generate an ignition file from the YAML.

```
data "ct_config" "worker" {
  content      = data.template_file.file.rendered
  strict       = true
  pretty_print = true
}
```

```
data "template_file" "file" {
  ...
  ...
  template = file("${path.module}/example.yml")
  vars = {
    script = file("${path.module}/script.sh")
  }
}
```

example.yml

```
storage:
  files:
    - path: "/opt/bin/script"
      mode: 0755
      contents: 
        inline: |
          ${script}
```

Error:

```
Error: Error unmarshaling yaml: yaml: line 187: could not find expected ':'

  on ../../modules/launch_template/launch_template.tf line 22, in data "ct_config" "worker":
  22: data "ct_config" "worker" {
```

If I change `${script}` to sample data then it works. Also, No matter what I put in the script.sh I am getting the same error.

Comment: What do you want the value of `${script}` to be?

Comment: I have updated the question. I am getting an error irrespective of the content. However, I want `${script}` to have the content of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this outcome (pseudocode):

```
storage:
  files:
    - path: "/opt/bin/script"
      mode: 0755
      contents: 
        inline: |
          {{content of script file}}
```

In your current implementation, all lines after the first loaded from script.sh will not be indented and will not be interpreted as desired (the entire script.sh content) by a YAML decoder.

Using [**indent**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/indent.html) you can correct the indentation and using the newer [**templatefile**](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) functuin you can use a slightly cleaner setup for the template:

```
data "ct_config" "worker" {
  content      = local.ct_config_content
  strict       = true
  pretty_print = true
}

locals {
  ct_config_content = templatefile("${path.module}/example.yml", {
    script = indent(10, file("${path.module}/script.sh"))
  })
}
```

For clarity, here is the example.yml template file (from the original question) to use with the code above:

```
storage:
  files:
    - path: "/opt/bin/script"
      mode: 0755
      contents: 
        inline: |
          ${script}
```

Comment: @admdrew note that this answer expects you to use the example.yml shown in the question. The YAML in my answer is psuedocode for the desired output and will not work as a template.

Comment: This is specifically an issue with https://github.com/poseidon/terraform-provider-ct (what is providing the `ct_config` data source that OP listed in their example) and is a newline issue with Ignition configs, not an indenting issue.

Comment: @admdrew please take a look at the question again. The error posted is an unmarshalling issue directly in Terraform. The fix I posted addresses that. Also, ct_config does transpile _to_ Ignition, so I'm not sure why the provider wouldn't address the second order issue you identified. I appreciate you weighing in. Where did you find the newline restriction documented?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue with `ct_config`, and figured it out today. You need to `base64encode` your script to ensure it's written correctly *without* newlines - without that, newlines in your script will make it to CT, which attempts to build an Ignition file, which cannot have newlines, causing the error you ran into originally.

Once encoded, you then just need to tell CT to `!!binary` the file to ensure Ignition correctly base64 decodes it on deploy:

```
data "template_file" "file" {
  ...
  ...
  template = file("${path.module}/example.yml")
  vars = {
    script = base64encode(file("${path.module}/script.sh"))
  }
}
```

```
storage:
  files:
    - path: "/opt/bin/script"
      mode: 0755
      contents: 
        inline: !!binary |
          ${script}
```